# Projects using Log4cpp library

Tags: c++, logging, log-rotation, log4cpp

I'm looking for a few projects that are using log4cpp for logging. Unfortunately I couldn't find any good examples of this library.
Now I have a simple working example of it but I need some more complex(at least for me ;-) ) examples like how to use log4cpp::Filter or log4cpp::LoggingEvent since I need filtering capabilities.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using log4cplus-1.2.0-rc3. you can get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cpp/files/log4cpp-1.1.x%20%28new%29/log4cpp-1.1/

I am able to get some example for log4cpp::Filter or log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent.

For log4cpp::Filter you need to configure configuration file.

For log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent you can find example in tests/performance_test/main.cxx

Just get source code for version you are using and look into example or test folder inside source code. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Careful, log4cpp != log4cplus != log4cxx